# Network exception corrected by System.out.println but I dont want to use it

Tags: java, exception, network-programming

This is my first question. I searched for hours to help myself, but there is no solution on the internet. 
My Program will only run when I insert a "System.out.println()", I want to tranfer a big file (mp3, 5Mb) by using tcp. I have much expierience working with java, but this is a very interesting failure.

Server and Client are at 128.0.0.1

This is my code for the client

```
public void receive(int port) {
        try {
            ServerSocket s = new ServerSocket(port);
            Socket socket = s.accept();
            BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(
                    socket.getInputStream());
            FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("dateiname.mp3");

            startzeit = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();

            byte[] b = new byte[32];
            while (in.available() > 0) {
                System.out.println(Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis()
                        - startzeit);
                in.read(b);
                fileOut.write(b);
                fileOut.flush();
                received += 1;
            }
            System.out.println("Feritg");
            fileOut.close();
        } catch (SocketException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

And the server

```
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.Socket;

public class FileTransfer {
    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    public static void send(File datei, InetAddress ip, int port)
            throws IOException 
        {
        Socket socket = new Socket(ip, port);
        BufferedOutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        FileInputStream fileIn = new FileInputStream(datei);
        while (fileIn.available() > 0) {
            byte[] b = new byte[32];
            fileIn.read(b);
            out.write(b);
            out.flush();
        }
        out.close();
        socket.close();
    }
}
```

And at least the exception trown by the server

```
Exception in thread "main" java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer: socket write error
 at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
 at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(Unknown Source)
 at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
 at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(Unknown Source)
 at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(Unknown Source)
 at FileTransfer.send(FileTransfer.java:20)
 at MainServer.main(MainServer.java:12)
```

Please help me!

Answer (score 2):

That exception means that the client closed the socket unexpectedly.

You probably don't want to use `available()` for your checks in the while loop. That function indicates only the number of bytes that can be read without blocking, not the total number of bytes in the file. What you want instead is something like this in the server:

```
while (fileIn.read(b) != -1) { ...
```

Similar code should be used in the client.

Also note that your code doesn't handle the case where you read less than 32 bytes. You should really do:

```
while ((n = fileIn.read(b))!= -1) {
  out.write(b, n);
  ...
```

Finally, 32 bytes is a really small size, you may get faster transfers using 4KB, 8KB or even larger buffers.

Comment: Also on the server side move the line 'byte[] b = new byte[32];' outside of the loop so that you allocate the buffer only once.

Comment: Also on the server side, you should have your socket I/O within a try block and do a catch for SocketException as you are doing on the client side.

Answer (score 1):

Don't reinvent the wheel. Use `IOUtils.copy(InputStream input, OutputStream output)` from Apache Commons IO library.